# Generalizations of the Rayleigh(-Beatty) theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

For a given irrational number $\alpha>0$ and a real number $\beta$,
the inhomogeneous [Beatty sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence)
sequence $S_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the set $\lbrace\lfloor n\alpha+\beta\rfloor:n=1,2,\dots\rbrace$
(the case $\beta=0$ corresponds to a homogeneous Beatty sequence).

If $\beta=0$, the two homogeneous Beatty sequences
$S_{\alpha_1,0}$ and $S_{\alpha_2,0}$ partition the set of positive integers
iff $1/\alpha_1+1/\alpha_2=1$. There is also a similar result for inhomogeneous
$S_{\alpha_1,\beta_1}$ and $S_{\alpha_2,\beta_2}$: assuming that neither
$n\alpha_1+\beta_1$ nor $n\alpha_2+\beta_2$ is an integer for $n=1,2,\dots$,
the sequences partition $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ iff $1/\alpha_1+1/\alpha_2=1$ and
$\beta_1/\alpha_1+\beta_2/\alpha_2=0$.

**Question.**
For a given $k\ge3$, what are the conditions on $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$
(and on $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k$ in the inhomogeneous case) to ensure that
the sets $S_{\alpha_i,\beta_i}$, $i=1,\dots,k$, partition the positive integers.

It looks like the book 
*Old and new problems and results in combinatorial number theory*
by P. Erdős and R.L. Graham (which I do not have) mentions a version
of the problem, but I am interested in some (possibly very recent) progress
in the direction. My interest is motivated by the study of functional
equations of the Mahler-type generating functions of the Beatty sequences.

Comment: This problem is much easier (but not all questions have been answered) if all of the $\alpha$ are integers, and is also much easier if any of the $\alpha$ are irrational. What are "Mahler-type generating functions"?

Comment: Kevin, as you have contributions in the area and so you are familiar (=cite) the Borwein's 1993 JNT paper, you know that the generating function of a Beatty sequence can be written as a Lambert series. Mahler was the first to show this systematically (and also to study arithmetical properties of values of the series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1973, [Fraenkel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165%2873%2990059-9) showed that, for fixed $k \geq 3$, if $\alpha_i = (2^k - 1)/2^{i-1}$ and $\beta_i = -2^{k-i} + 1$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots k$, then the $k$ Beatty sequences $S_{\alpha_i,\beta_i} := \lbrace{\lfloor n\alpha_i + \beta_i\rfloor\rbrace}_{n\geq 1}$ partition the positive integers. Many other cases have been proved by [Simpson](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X%2891%2990293-B) (1991).

Fraenkel also conjectured that any partition of the positive integers into $k \geq 3$ Beatty sequences $S_{\alpha_i,\beta_i}$, with $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ real and $0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \cdots < \alpha_k$, satisfies $\alpha_i = (2^k - 1)/2^{i-1}$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$.

To date, Fraenkel's conjecture has been proved for up to $k=7$ sequences. I would recommend taking a look at [this paper](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~tijdeman/tij3.ps) by Tijdeman (2001), who proved the conjecture for $k = 5, 6$ (and for $k = 3$ in an earlier paper). [Altman, Gaujal, Hordijk](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.3158) (1997) proved it for $k = 4$, and more recently, [Barát and Varjú](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357703900000) (2003) verified the conjecture for $k=7$. It's a tantalising open problem, which I have [dabbled with recently](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2008.04.006) too (albeit from a different point of view).

Comment: Fraenkel's conjecture was resolved if any of the $\alpha_i$ are irrational by Ron Graham in the early 1970s.

Comment: There is a paper by Graham on covering the positive integers by disjoint Beatty sets with at least one irrational parameter; J Combinatorial Theory, Series A 15 (1973) 354-358, MR 48 #3911, but judging from the review it does not claim to settle Fraenkel's conjecture. Maybe it does, but I don't see it. 

Comment: Yes, here is the doi link to Graham's paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(73)90084-8. Rob's preprint (published in Discr. Math. 2000) is really great at explaining everything. Many thanks to Amy, Kevin and Gerry!